# JS Method Declaration - define method outside class body

Tags: javascript, oop

When I create class in JavaScript I can define static methods outside class body. Can I actually also add definition of non-static methods?

```
class Class {
    fun() {console.log("some method")} //how to put it outside Class body?
}

Class.static_fun = function () {
    console.log("some static method");
}

var object = new Class();
Class.static_fun();
object.fun();
```

Comment: I believe ```Class.static_fun``` will not be accessible from instances ```object.static_fun()``` because ```static_fun``` is not declared on the prototype

Comment: Yes, how much do you know about how `class` works in JS?

Comment: "*Can I actually also add definition of non-static methods?*" - Sure: `Class.prototype.fun = function() { … };`